# i'm trying to get 2 lists in 1 python

Tags: python, list

I am new to programming so I apologise in advance for not using the right terms. I am using Python. I have a series of lists of this form `[n1,...,n13]` and an `array [0,0,1]` (unchanging). I would like to append the array to the list in such a way that the output is of this form.

```
x =[[[n1,...,n13], [0,0,1]], [[m1,...,m13], [0,0,1]], [[x1,...,x13], [0,0,1]],...]
```

I have no clue how to do it.
Also, in my lists `['n1','n2'...]`, my numbers are between quotations, would I need to get rid of them if I want to use them elsewhere?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: So your numbers are strings... do you need to calculate with them anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, I do - thanks XORcist

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension to iterate list elements and add array to it

```
In [15]: a =[0,0,1]

In [16]: l =[['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'],['1','2','3']]

In [18]: print [[i ,a] for i in l]
[[['1', '2', '3'], [0, 0, 1]], [['1', '2', '3'], [0, 0, 1]], [['1', '2', '3'], [0, 0, 1]]]
```

**EDIT:**

And to convert  string to int

```
In [19]: print [[map(int,i) ,a] for i in l]
[[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]]]
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Raydel Miranda and if you are updating array somewhere else in the code,

[@Raydel Miranda - Sorry I can't upvote or leave comment due to my low score. You raised a valid point though]

```
In [21]: x
Out[21]: [[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]]]

In [22]: a.append(1)
```

would change

```
In [23]: x
Out[23]: 
[[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]]]
```

hence, you could use what Raydel Miranda suggested below or

```
In [24]: x= [[map(int,i) ,list(a)] for i in l]

In [25]: x
Out[25]: 
[[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]]]

In [26]: a.append(2)

In [27]: x
Out[27]: 
[[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1]]]
```

Comment: Did you mean `[[i,a] for in in l]` ?

Comment: @mtrw, Thanks I was just editing that :)

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, now I got the power to up vote u :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy      # copy is need it for prevent putting the same reference of
                 # array in all list elements.

lst = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]  # Some list
array = [0,0,1]                    # Some array

result = [[x, copy.copy(array)]  for x in lst]   # Add a [x, <copy_of_array>] pair to result
                                                 # for each x in lst.
```

Here is another way to do the same:

```
import copy

lst = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
array = [0, 0, 1]
result = []

for (elem in lst):
     result.append([copy.copy(elem), copy.copy(x)])
```

**EDIT** : Why to use copy?

Just follow the next example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]  # We have some list
>>> k = []       # another list.
>>> k.append(l)  # now, k is: [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> l[0] = "changed" # Change the first element of l. Now l == ["changed", 2, 3]
>>> print(k)  # What is in k value ??
>>> [["changed", 2, 3]] # k value change too!!!
```

in order to avoid that you must use copy (or equivalent).

```
>>> k.append(copy.copy(l))
```